# Does the Redis PHP extension installed through PECL work on Mac M1?

Tags: php, redis, apple-m1, apple-silicon

The Redis server is running successfully using Homebrew with `brew services start redis`.
The PECL Redis installer appears to work with `sudo pecl install redis` , giving the following output:

```
Build process completed successfully
Installing '/opt/homebrew/Cellar/php@7.4/7.4.28/pecl/20190902/redis.so'
install ok: channel://pecl.php.net/redis-5.3.7
Extension redis enabled in php.ini
```

If I use `php --ini`, this is the output:

```
Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'redis.so' (tried: /opt/homebrew/lib/php/pecl/20190902/redis.so (dlopen(/opt/homebrew/lib/php/pecl/20190902/redis.so, 0x0009): tried: '/opt/homebrew/lib/php/pecl/20190902/redis.so' (mach-o file, but is an incompatible architecture (have 'x86_64', need 'arm64e')), '/usr/local/lib/redis.so' (no such file), '/usr/lib/redis.so' (no such file)), /opt/homebrew/lib/php/pecl/20190902/redis.so.so (dlopen(/opt/homebrew/lib/php/pecl/20190902/redis.so.so, 0x0009): tried: '/opt/homebrew/lib/php/pecl/20190902/redis.so.so' (no such file), '/usr/local/lib/redis.so.so' (no such file), '/usr/lib/redis.so.so' (no such file))) in Unknown on line 0
```

The redis.so library is in /opt/homebrew/lib/php/pecl/20190902.

Is there any way to get this library working on Mac M1?

Comment: https://github.com/shivammathur/homebrew-extensions

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can run `pecl` with `arch` to ensure that the architecture is `arm64`.

```
arch -arm64 sudo pecl install redis
```

Alternatively, you can use a brew tap I maintain ([shivammathur/extensions](https://github.com/shivammathur/homebrew-extensions)).

```
brew tap shivammathur/extensions
brew install redis@7.4
```

Answer (score 1):

I have done the same like accepted answer

`arch -arm64 sudo pecl install redis`

But that didn't work for me immediately. I needed to reinstall redis.

`pecl uninstall redis`

`pecl install redis`