# MAMP ext mailparse is not loading, not sure if installed correctly PHP 7.1.33

Tags: php, mamp, php-extension, pecl, php-7.1

i started to work on web application which uses PHP 7.1.33 - which i did set up in MAMP, but I have problem to get extension mailparse - which I tried and probably installed through PECL commands.

But when i run

```
php -i | grep mailparse
```

There is no output - so it seems its not installed, but:

```
pecl install mailparse-3.1.3
```

Outputs:

```
pecl/mailparse is already installed and is the same as the released version 3.1.3
```

My php.ini

```
extension=mailparse.so - enabled
```

[My phpinfo()](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1-h74u3r7yLrr5xoJOJIoyZm5apsfL8rf/view?usp=sharing)

Thanks for any help

Comment: there could be problem with my M1 Mac (Arm), [05-Oct-2022 15:55:50 UTC] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php7.1.33/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20160303/mailparse.so' - dlopen(/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php7.1.33/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20160303/mailparse.so, 0x0009): tried: '/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php7.1.33/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20160303/mailparse.so' (mach-o file, but is an incompatible architecture (have 'x86_64', need 'arm64e')), '/usr/lib/mailparse.so' (no such file) in Unknown on line 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to let the others know, problem was finally with M1 Macbook (Arm) architecture, so i uninstalled the extension with PECL and then installed one, which is compactible with command

```
arch -arm64 sudo pecl install mailparse-3.1.3
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71246992/does-the-redis-php-extension-installed-through-pecl-work-on-mac-m1